# How to determine the divisor associated to a function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the surface defined by the $xy-zt = 0 \in \mathbb{P}^3$. I am asked to find the divisor of $x/y$. It's completely trivial where the $0$'s and poles have to be for this rational function. I can view this function in each affine piece. Is the divisor I'm looking for some linear combination of curves that include these points at infinity? Somehow it seems like there are any number of curves which could work, which is why I know something must be wrong with my understanding. There should be only finitely many such curves, but if all I know is that they must contain zeroes and poles, why aren't there lots of such curves?

Conceptually I feel okay about what divisors are, but I struggle to actually compute anything with them at all. Also, since this problem is from Shafarevich (but not homework, just reading), I don't have any high-powered weaponry to deal with this at all. Somehow it should just be algebraic, but I don't know what it is I'm after precisely. Could someone hold my hand through this computation? I'm reasonably sure I could work out other similar examples from there.

Comment: You need to find the subspaces of $xy-zt=0$ on which this function is zero or infinity. The divisor is the formal sum of the null subspace minus the pole subspace. The corresponding curves are reducible, both the positive and the negative part can be decomposed into 2 irreducible components each. I'm not sure what your confusion stems from, perhaps if you would show us your thoughts we could point out your error.

Comment: @AntonFetisov  By 'this function' you refer to the rational function $x/y$, yes? It's pretty obvious that this is $0$ when $x$ is $0$, and has poles when $y=0$. My impression was that such a divisor just had to contain these zeroes and poles, not actually be the zeros and poles. If either $x$ or $y$ are $0$, we're left with $zt=0$, corresponding to the components where $z$ or $t$ are $0$. These should all be of order $1$. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed looking for a finite linear combination of curves. If I can say it like this: $\mbox{div}(x/y) = \mbox{div}_0(x/y) - \mbox{div}_{\infty}(x/y)$. That is, the divisor will be the zero locus of your (rational) function $x/y$ minus the pole locus.

The zero locus is of course where $x=0$ on the surface, which you can determine is the pair of lines $L_1 := \{x = z = 0\}$ and $L_2:=\{x=t=0\}$ (call this union $C:=L_1\cup L_2$). The pole locus is then where $y=0$ which is the pair of lines $L_3 :=\{y=z=0\}$ and $L_4:=\{y=t=0\}$ (call this union $D:=L_3\cup L_4$).

So the divisor you want is $C-D$.

Comment: It seems like the pole locus and the zero locus are the same here, since $x$ and $y$ appear in the same term. Did I miss something?

Comment: They are not the same curves - the zero locus is the union of the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, while the pole locus is the union of the lines $L_3$ and $L_4$. All four lines are different lines. Moreover, while the equation of the surface ($xy-zt=0$) has the monomial term $xy$ as the only occurrence of both $x$ and $y$, the (rational) function you are dealing with is $x/y$ which distinguishes the behavior relating to the zero loci of each variable.

Comment: @AlfredYerger The zero locus and pole locus can never be the same, they can't even intersect since they are defined as preimages of two distinct points on $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @AntonFetisov I'm afraid that's not true. The zero locus and pole locus I defined above do intersect. And that's not wrong because the rational function does not define a regular map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ - only a rational map.

Comment: @AntonFetisov One could blow up precisely these points of intersection in which case the pullback of the rational function would yield a regular map from the blowup to $\mathbb{P}^1$. In that case, as you say, the (proper transforms of the) two loci would not intersect.

Comment: @john oops, my bad. But I assume they still can't coincide... right?

Comment: @AntonFetisov exactly - on the blowup they can't coincide because then you have this regular map so, as you say, preimages of the different points can't intersect.

Comment: @john No, I mean on the variety itself. Is it always true that the positive and negative part of function divisor have no common components? Can't imagine how it would look if it did. I.e. is it true that a rational map can be undefined only in codimension >1 ?

Comment: @AntonFetisov Ah sorry, I just realized that's what you meant. Regarding the rational map, yes - the domain of a rational map (on a smooth variety) can always be extended to the complement of a closed set of codimension > 1 (that's why rational maps from smooth curves extend to regular ones) Regarding the components, one needs to say perhaps more precisely what the definition of the zero/pole locus divisors are. There's something to be said in general about valuations/multiplicities. Here I didn't say that because the numerator and denominator were relatively prime and each of degree 1.